# A kind of Linked List but Don't understand exactly

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list, type-conversion

I asked this before, but no one answered so revise my questions. I have tried to analyze this codes but it doesn't make sense for me. This time hopefully someone give me an idea or correct my misunderstanding.

`char * p` pointing to `command` array is type-casted to `CMD_BLOCK *` after getting thru a couple of functions.

```
                         extern CHGR_CMD command[96]
                          +---+---+---+---+
(CMD_BLOCK *(char *p)) -> | CHGR_CMD      | command[0]
                          +---+---+---+---+
                          | CHGR_CMD      | command[1]
                          +---+---+---+---+ ....
                          | ....          | command[95]
                          +---+---+---+---+
```

Here is a struct of `CMD_BLOCK` and union `CHGR_CMD`

```
typedef struct cmd_block {
 struct cmd_block *next;
 short type;
 short unused;
 CHGR_CMD c; //Union
} CMD_BLOCK;


typedef union chgr_cmd {
  NET_HDR n; //struct
  CHGR_SC_SETUP    su;//struct
  CHGR_SC_START    st;//struct
  CHGR_SC_STOP     sp;//struct
  ....
} CHGR_CMD;
```

the below variables are used in `cmd_init()`

```
#define CMD_OFFSET  (sizeof(struct cmd_block *) + 2*sizeof(short))
block_size = sizeOf(CHGR_CMD)
size = 96*sizeOf(CHGR_CMD)
```

Especially, I don't get the for loop below:

```
int cmd_init(register char* p, register long size, int block_size)
{
  int i;

  if((size <= 0) || (block_size <= 0) || (block_size > size))
    return(-1);

  cmd_out_head = NULL;//extern var
  cmd_out_tail = NULL;//extern var
  cmd_free_space = NULL;//extern var
  block_size += CMD_OFFSET;// turn to be size of CMD_BLOCK

  cmd_blocks_free = 0;
  cmd_blocks_used = 0;

  for(i=0; size >= block_size; size-=block_size, i++, p+=block_size) {
    ((CMD_BLOCK *)(p))->next = cmd_free_space;
    cmd_free_space = (CMD_BLOCK *)(p);
    cmd_blocks_free++;
  }

  cmd_b = NULL;
  status_seq_clear();

  return(i);
}
```

`for loop` iterates until `96` which is size of `command` array.

`p+=block_size` keeps adding size of `CMD_BLOCK` ---> **I don't get how this works?.** Initially type of array was `CHGR_CMD` and type-casting to `char *` then another casting to `CMD_BLOCK *` then increasing the size of `CMD_BLOCK`in for-loop??

I am not sure but assumed that type of command array is now turning to be `CMD_BLOCK` after a couple of type-casting.

**Another thing I don't get is this codes:**

```
((CMD_BLOCK *)(p))->next = cmd_free_space;
cmd_free_space = (CMD_BLOCK *)(p);
```

It doesn't seem like linking together. cmd_free_space seems to point the last element of the array while `* p` gets increased by the size of `CMD_BLOCK`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the cast from `char*` to `CMD_BLOCK*`, It is hard to tell without looking at more code, but most probably the original programmer wanted to give some opacity to the `p` parameter, that is, maybe he/she didn't want to expose the fact that the function is receiving an array of `CMD_BLOCK` structs.

This opacity is sometimes exercised on certain APIs to try to minimize the chance that a data structure is directly manipulated by the programmer, bypassing the tested API.

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) for more details on opaque pointers.

In order to remove the opacity, a programmer needs to explicitly cast the opaque pointer to the concrete type that is actually being passed. This is what seems that is being done with the line `((CMD_BLOCK *)(p))->next = cmd_free_space;`

As to what the `for` block is doing, it is actually building a reversed linked list from an array of contiguous `CMD_BLOCK` structures.  The first node's `next` pointer is initialized to `NULL`, becoming the tail of the linked list, the second node's `next` pointer is pointed to the first node and so forth, until the last block becomes the head of the list and seems to be accessible through the `cmd_free_space` variable as you point out.

** EDIT **
To better illustrate how the list is built, I'll try to step through the first two iterations.

```
iteration 1
   State at the beginning of the iteration:
      cmd_free_space is NULL;
      p is pointing to the first element of the array.
   Execution:
      p->next = cmd_free_space; p->next becomes NULL;
      cmd_free_space = p;       cmd_free_space is pointing to the first element of the array
      p += block_size;          p is now pointing to the second element of the array

iteration 2
    State at the beginning of the iteration:
       cmd_free_space is pointing to the first element of the array
       p is pointing to the second element of the array.
    Execution:
       p->next = cmd_free_space; p->next = first element of the array (link is done)
       cmd_free_space = p;       cmd_free_space is now pointing to the second element of the array
       p += block_size;          p is now pointing to the third element of the array
```

and so on...

** END OF EDIT **

<s>I would remove from the `for` block the `i` variable, as it is useless (it is neither controlling the number of iterations nor indexing anything).</s>

** EDIT: **
I hadn't noticed that the ´i´ variable is returned from the function, so it most probably has a purpose, outside of the function.  The function is actually returning the number of elements that were actually processed in the for loop.
** END OF EDIT **

The fact that `blocksize` is a variable parameter and not simply `sizeof(CMD_BLOCK)` may also indicate that the function can initialize a linked list with an array of structs that contain as first member a `CMD_BLOCK` struct, but that also carry additional data. By adding `blocksize` to the pointer that is walking the array, the `for` loop would effectively skip over the extra data.

This initialization of an array into a linked list may seem a strange thing to do,  but I would guess that the programmer needed the flexibility of inserting commands in the middle of the list without having to copy/move elements in the original array to make space.

Comment: Thank you for commenting my questions. First of all, I don't get the reversed linked-list that you explained. Actually `cmd_out_head` and `cmd_out_tail` are never used in this codes,so only `*next` in `CMD_BLOCK` is used for pointing the next node. Initially, `*p` indicates the first node of **command** array then keep going down until hit the last which is `command[95]` while `for-loop`.

Comment: For the first time`*next` points `CMD_BLOCK* cmd_free_space` which is `null`initially,then assign the current node to `* cmd_free_space`. After p+=block_size, `*p` moves to next node in array. However `* cmd_free_space` only points `*p` that moved to 2nd node by `p+=block_size`at the end of loop,so `*cmd_free_space` actually points the 2nd node indicated by `* p`. Now `*p` indicates the 2nd node of array, and `* next` of 2nd node points `* cmd_free_space` which indicates `* p` pointing 2nd node.

Comment: Again, by `p+=block_size`, `* p` moves to 3rd nodes, so where the `* cmd_free_space` points at is 3rd node indicated by `* p`. The problem I thought is every node has `* next` pointing the same `* cmd_free_space`, as loop goes along, `* p` keeps moving to the next node until the max size of array. Therefore, every `* next` in node points the same node at the end of loop. That's my understanding ,but not sure honestly.

Comment: Hi, I modified my answer stepping through the first two iterations of the for loop, hoping it becomes clearer. The `next`pointers are not pointing to the same node because `cmd_free_space` is updated *before* the `p` pointer is incremented by `block_size`; Your confusion seems that you think that when you alter `p`, the values of the `next` pointers are modified,  they are not.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was confused about `*p` and `command[]`. I thought two locations are different, but all same. Also, I understand why it is called **reversed linked-list**

Comment: Glad I was able to help  =)

Comment: Initially, `command[]` starts as type of `CHGR_CMD` and type-casting to `char *`,then end up casting to `CMD_BLOCK *`. I guess, the programmer wanted to keep **lay-out of members** inside structure, which is `CMD_BLOCK` by casting `char *`

Comment: `Struct CMD_BLOCK` contains `Union CHGR_CMD`, so as long as keep the offset of members in the structure, we can access any members of structure indicated by `pointer variable`. That's why the programmer did `block_size+=CMD_OFFSET`. Initially, `block_size` is `sizeOf(CHGR_CMD)` but adding up `CMD_OFFSET`, which is size of members in `CMD_BLOCK`,turns to `size of CMD_BLOCK`